# Updating value in Linq to SQL IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Using Linq to SQL:

```
if(!parentlist.childlist.Contains(row1))
      parentlist.childlist.Add(row1);
else
```

How do I update the required childlist row with row1? Each row of the child list has a unique id.

`parentlist` implements `IEnumerable` and `childlist` is `IList`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it this way. You need to select the chidlist item out of the datacontaxt and then add the row to it and submit back.

Its not satisfactory really, but i think its just one of the annoying limitations of linq2sql.